# How to replace any character in any position according to the pattern

Tags: java, android, algorithm, kotlin, format

I have a problem like the below:

Given a string and a character and position need replace, for example as below:

Input:
string: str = ABCDEFGH, prefix = "_" and position = 3,
Output:
result = AB_CDE_FGH

Input:
string: str = 10000000, prefix = "_" and position = 3,
Output:
result = 10_000_000

Input:
string: str = 10000000, prefix = "_" and position = 2,
Output:
result = 10_00_00_00

This is my code:

```
fun convertNumberByCharacter(pattern:String,position: Int,characters: String):String{
    val strBuilder = StringBuilder()
    val arr = pattern.toCharArray()
    return if (arr.size>position){
        for (i in 0..arr.size-1){
            if (i%position==0){
                strBuilder.append(characters)
            }
            strBuilder.append(arr[i])
        }
        strBuilder.toString()

    }else{
        pattern
    }
}
```

***Note: DecimalFormat and NumberFormat cannot be used in this problem.***

Please, Anyone could help me. Thank you.

Comment: Hi there, here are some hints that might help you find an answer. It's important to start counting from the end of the string (your current loop starts at the left). To go 'backwards', you could [reverse](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/reversed.html) your string. As String is an Iterable you can [chunk](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) it into `position` sizes, and then 'insert' your separator using [`joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) on the chunked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation using standard Kotlin library functions - no need for mucking around with indices.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    println(convert("ABCDEFGH", 3, "_")) // AB_CDE_FGH
    println(convert("10000000", 3, "_")) // 10_000_000
    println(convert("10000000", 2, "_")) // 10_00_00_00
}

fun convert(input: String, position: Int, separator: String) =
  input
    // reverse the string
    // e.g. HGFEDCBA
    .reversed()
    // split into chunks 
    // e.g. [HGF], [EDC], [BA]
    .chunked(position) 
    // join the chunks back into a string, with a separator 
    // e.g. HGF_EDC_BA
    .joinToString(separator)
    // un-reverse the string - done!
    // e.g. AB_CDE_FGH
    .reversed()
```

It's important to start counting from the end of the string (your current loop starts at the left). To go 'backwards' I've [reversed](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/reversed.html) the input string. As String is an Iterable I've used [chunk](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) to split it into `position` sizes, and then 'inserted' the separator using [joinToString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) on the chunked list. Finally I call `reverse` again to undo the initial reversal.

Comment: This's a beautiful answer, but I'm not found "reversed()" in String with Kotlin, So Can you tell me which version of Kotlin you are using? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Thanks! From what I can see in the docs `reversed()` has been in since 1.0, and for all platforms since 1.3. [Here's the source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/bde055fe5c6be9816b4126133a12fb41eae0e0cf/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Strings.kt#L660). I'm using 1.5 Kotlin/JVM. What version do you have?

Comment: I'm so sorry because my mistake, Thank you again.

Comment: No need to apologise! If you had a problem please explain what it was and how you resolved it, in case someone else has the same issue and you could help them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
val str = "ABCD"
val prefix = "_"
val position = 3
val result = StringBuilder()

val offset = position - str.length % position
for (i in str.indices) {
    if (i != 0 && (i + offset) % position == 0) {
        result.append(prefix)
    }
    result.append(str[i])
}
println(result)
```

I think `reverse` string then loop, add prefix at a position then `reverse` again also solve this problem

Comment: Can you tell me the reason why you can calculate offset?

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way to accomplish this would be to use a combination of [chunked()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) and [joinToString()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html). Unfortunately, stdlib only provides `chunked()` that counts from the left and we need to count from the right here. Still, I think it is cleaner to implement `chunkedRight()` and use it with `joinToString()`.

```kotlin
fun CharSequence.chunkedRight(size: Int): List<String> {
    if (isEmpty()) return emptyList()

    val fullChunks = length / size
    val firstSize = length - fullChunks * size

    // capacity may be too big by one - no problem here
    return ArrayList<String>(fullChunks + 1).apply {
        if (firstSize > 0) {
            add(substring(0, firstSize))
        }

        (firstSize until length step size).forEach {
            add(substring(it, it + size))
        }
    }
}
```

Or alternatively:

```kotlin
fun CharSequence.chunkedRightSequence(size: Int): Sequence<String> {
    if (isEmpty()) return emptySequence()

    val firstSize = (length - 1) % size + 1
    return sequenceOf(substring(0, firstSize)) +
            (firstSize until length step size).asSequence()
                .map { substring(it, it + size) }
}
```

Then we can use it like this:

```kotlin
println("ABCDEFGH".chunkedRight(3).joinToString("_"))
println("10000000".chunkedRight(3).joinToString("_"))
println("10000000".chunkedRight(2).joinToString("_"))
```

Or we can create a specialized function for this.

Comment: It feels like `chunkedRight()` should be really more concise, but this first chunk makes it hard to use `map()` or similar utils and keep the good performance (so no list copying and no conditionals for each chunk). I'm open to suggestions for improvements.

Comment: Yep, After I'm put a question, I'm received so many answers about "chunked" and "joinToString" and I'm seeing some answers very beautifully, including your answer, Thank you.