# How to format number to have thousands separator?

Tags: kotlin, number-formatting

As input, I get a number, for example `1000000`, it needs to be converted into a `String` that will look like this: `1.000.000`

Also, the number can be `750000` or any other, it must be converted to `750.000` and so on (the number can be either less than 10 thousand or more than 10 million)

How can I do that?

Comment: You could try and adapt the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69368546/4161471

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be using [java.text.DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```kotlin
fun formatter(n: Int) =
    DecimalFormat("#,###")
        .format(n)
        .replace(",", ".")

println(formatter(1000000)) // => 1.000.000
println(formatter(750000))  // => 750.000
```

However, do note that the dot (`.`) symbol is commonly used as a Decimal separator (or monetary decimal separator)

So I would advice using `,` instead of of `.`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3BCsIwEETv/YoluSRQUnsQodiCIIJnvyCUtESTtMRVFPHbY1ILUnBgD7vzZucyoNEuBG3HwSOc5V0KVA8Ue9VqK81h8FZilnU3B1Zqx6TvrxXsvJfP7Qm9dn3D4ZUBJKKbaFSeuQqODjnU0UlavGOE5pRSwmczSXyzzC2OXo1GtoqRnORARExEd4ytaBz7tZWrSZxDUUDdQCniluYvvVnP8EzHfWLfIXwA)

---

**Update**:

If your intention is having a German locale (Thanks @AndrewL) formatting, then configure the [DecimalFormatSymbols](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) with the correct locale:

```kotlin
fun formatter(n: Int) =
    DecimalFormat("#,###", DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMANY)).format(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5LC8IwEITv@RVLe0mgpHoQoWih4ANBPejJYyy1RPMo6SqK@NtrrIIUxIE9DPMxsyeLSpqmkbqyDuEoLoJjcUU@KXKphZpZpwWS//H2pvdW1R3qjFLxpc2FKgg5nA1oIQ0VrqwTyJwTt9EWnTRlyuBOAF7EoS3DwlGTwMIgg7FPvDpjNAijMAyDCH79QN@TfD7drLL1jjH@bqWGEV9W@UlUhn6n@r1WjEEcwziFPvfudT/p4eADf2jvW/bRNE8)

Answer (score 3):

1. use `String.format`
2. with `%,d` which means a decimal with thousand separator
3. then pick a locale where the thousand separator is a `.` like
   Germany:

```
println(String.format(Locale.GERMANY, "%,d", 1000000))
1.000.000
println(String.format(Locale.GERMANY, "%,d", 750000))
750.000
```